# All Chern numbers as mapping degree?

Tags: topology, quantum-hall-effect

The Chern number of Haldane model can be interpreted as a mapping degree from $T^2$ (1BZ) to $S^2$ (Bloch sphere). The question is whether all the Chern numbers can be interpreted in this way.

In particular, the integer quantum hall wave functions written in the Magnetic BZ are Jacobi theta functions. We can calculate its Berry curvature and integrate over BZ and get a Chern number. How to interpret it as a mapping degree since the Hamiltonian for each k is infinite dimensional?